# Return a conditional if statement based on list length

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to create a conditional `if` function that displays a result if the length of the list is greater than 5:

```
{% if length(photos) > 5 %}
...
{% endif %}
```

However, I get `Could not parse the remainder: '(photos)' from 'length(photos)'`, where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't Python use `len()` for length functions, not `length()`?

Comment: @Conduit OP is asking about Jinja template engine here not Python.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Oops! Mislead by Python tag - sorry, OP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
{% if photos|length > 5 %}
...
{% endif %}
```